# draw profile picture in android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, shadow

I want a result like this: 
[image]
and instead of that black box you put a profile picture and I want to kept the shadow underneath the profile picture

how to do this,

I tried this code but it gives no result

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@drawable/item_profil_amis"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgprof"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/profle"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout, instead of a LinearLayout, for better positioning control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) tool of android with shadow effect made in photoshop.

**example:**

[image]

Comment: but how to make a profile picture inside this image?